# Cross-platform mobile development in Xamarin

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin

I just started Xamarin and wanted to know which is good among this 3:

1. PCL
2. File linking
3. Project linking

When should I use what and why? Please give a good description.

Note: I wanted to take all my app to different app store/google play/market place.

Which one should I use to make thing work best for me and why?

Comment: It depends.  In general, PCL is probably the best approach, but there are some circumstances where it won't work, or may not be the best choice.  But there is no single correct answer to this question.

Comment: FYI: There are a number of articles on this subject at Xamarin. Start here and follow the links. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @kenny has pointed out, here is an article from Xamarin that specifically addresses pros and cons of each approach: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/